# Logging in async methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have this program, that have two async methods, which wants to write something in log at the same time.

```
class Program
{
    private const string LOG_FILE = "Log.txt";
    private static object _Lock = new object();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();

        new Task(p.Func1).Start();
        new Task(p.Func2).Start();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private async void Func1()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            this.Log("1");
    }

    private async void Func2()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            this.Log("2");
    }

    private void Log(string msg)
    {
        lock(_Lock)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(LOG_FILE, msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Output is something like this "11222222222211111111" and could change. Why output is not a "12121212121212121212"?

If I'm correct, then Func2 will wait till Func1 write "1" to log file. Then Func2 will write "2" and Func1 will be waiting.

Comment: It is not recommended to use `Task.Start` instance method. Use `Task.Run` static method instead.

Comment: `Func2 will wait till Func1 write "1" to log file. Then Func2 will write "2" and Func1 will be waiting` - and that's where you're wrong :) It's entirely *possible* the first thread will write everything before the second thread even starts.

Comment: Design of the Async methods are incorrect, shall await in complete chain and Mark all methods Async

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Async doesn't mean that you run alternately. it means you give anyone the option to run. (same goes from grabbing the lock)

It kind of goes like this

- Task1 start, find the lock and take it
- then after x miliseconds it is preempted (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)), often happening due to file accessing but it also happens after a certain amount of time to give the OS  the chance to do other things.
- Now Task 2 starts is given a chance to run. task 2 finds task 1 still has the lock and waits.
- Tasks 1 continues and releases the lock and might then be preempted again.
- Then the first thread who is woken up to take the lock again (which might be either thread) that thread will get the next lock.

The result is that any thread can log in any order. or 1 thread finishes all it's work before the other thread is given a chance to run.

As Yacoub noted it can also happens that Task 1 & 2 run on different cores. But the principle of lock grabbing still applies. The first thread who has it will execute. Depending on the algorithm (usually at OS or even processor/assembly level) there might not be a fairness/queueing mechanism in place for the lock statement.

Comment: Please note also that it is very much possible that the two Tasks are running in a truly parallel fashion if the machine has more than one physical core.

Comment: @YacoubMassad Truly parallel until they need to do IO (such as writing to a file), that is.

Comment: @Rob, yes. I was mainly talking about preemption. If each thread runs on a different physical core (and there is not a competition from other applications), then theoretically there is no need for context switching.

Comment: A context switch will happen periodically even if it was just for the OS to determine if further context switching is needed

Comment: @Batavia, I am not really sure this changes a lot. For example, the OS can use one physical core and leave other cores to their current threads. Does the OS have to preempt all the running threads?

Comment: @Yacoub, that is very possible. however on most machines there are so many tasks/processes running that all threads will be preempted. at least some amount of the time. There might be cases where it doens't happen. Just like 12121212121212 could be a real result. The odds of it happening are slim though.